# pdfmake problem displaying accurate page numbers

Tags: pdfmake

I'm using pdfmake to generate a document that contains a number of sub-documents, e.g. a PDF containing invoices; each invoice is a logical document inside the PDF document.

I have a requirement that in the footer or header of each page I show "Page  of " where both those numbers are relative to a single invoice, and *not* the overall document.

The header and footer callbacks look good, but only specify the page number and count relative to the entire document, and the pageBreakBefore callback doesn't generate anything like the documented information, and in any case I can't figure out how I could use it here.

This doesn't seem like a unique requirement, so hopefully I'm just missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I believe that pdkmake's header and footer function's arguments can only contain the global pageCount.**

There is however a way to reproduce the behavior that you want, if you **handle manually the pageBreaks** :

```
const realPageIndexes = [];
let currSubPdfIdx = 0;
let currPageCountForSubPdf = 0;

const getPageBreak = (newSubPdfIdx: number) => {

    if (currSubPdfIdx !== newSubPdfIdx) {
        currSubPdfIdx = newSubPdfIdx;
        currPageCountForSubPdf = 0;
    } else {
        currPageCountForSubPdf += 1;
    }

    realPageIndexes.push(currPageCountForSubPdf);
    return {text: '', pageBreak: 'after'}; // return elem causing the pageBreak
}
```

The footer function, filling the page numbers, is called once the document definition generation is done.

If you handle every overflow by yourself, by calling getPageBreak(currentSubPdfIndex) at the end of each page, you will end up knowing which sub-Pdf is displayed in each page :

- I display part of the 1rst subPdf in page 1:
- I display the end of 1rst subPdf in page 2
- I display 2nd subPdf in page3
- I display 3rd subPdf in page4 ....

.

```
let subPdfIdx = 0;
pdfContent.push(subPdf1FirstPart)
pdfContent.push(getPageBreak(subPdfIdx))
pdfContent.push(subPdf1SecondPart)
pdfContent.push(getPageBreak(subPdfIdx))

subPdfIdx++;
pdfContent.push(subPdf2)
pdfContent.push(getPageBreak(subPdfIdx))

subPdfIdx++;
pdfContent.push(subPdf3)
pdfContent.push(getPageBreak(subPdfIdx))
```

realPageIndexes[] then looks like :

[ 1, 1, 2, 3 ];

The only step left is to tell the footer function to use the page counts we just created instead of the global page count :

```
const documentDefinition = {
    content: [YOUR CONTENT],
    footer: (currPage, allPages) => 'subPdf index is ' + realPageIndexes[currPage];
}
```

Please note that this method will fail if you don't handle overflows correctly:

if for example a paragraph is too big to fit a page, and you call getPageBreak() after that, pdfmake will automatically create a new page for the end of the paragraph (page which is untracked in our realPageIndexes) and then add the page caused by your getPageBreak() right after the end of the text. So just make sure not to overflow the page :)